# Django Form Submit Unicode Character

Tags: python, django, unicode

I writing an Django application to let user enter a filename and performing some process.  In normal case if user enter the file name only contains alphanumeric characters, the process will finished normally.

If user enter the filename contains Unicode characters, such as Chinese or Japanese, the process will ended with exception (HTML 500 Error).  I check the form data submitted to server, the file name field will converted to unicode strings, for example

```
"\u30a2\u30af\u30bb\u30b9\u6a29\u9650\u4f53\u7cfb\u5b9a\u7fa9\u66f8.xls"
```

In this case, for example, use pyminizip to zip the file, it will raise the exception error and the process stop.

Is there any ways that I can convert the unicode string back to it original text, such as Chinese or Japanese character?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Django handles forms using its [default charset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-charset) for forms. This seems more like a data processing or storage issue. Depending on the database you use, the default character encoding will vary:

1. [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html) - latin1
2. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CHARSET-SUPPORTED) - varies by [locale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/app-initdb.html).

I'd change the character set of your database or transform your data before it gets there.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.  I have no problem on updating the information into DB but my problem is when I get the file name from request.POST, I need to open the specified file but because the file name changed to Unicode string, the exception was raised.  So I need to found out how can I change the Unicode string of the file name to its original Chinese or Japanese characters so that I can access the file from program.